# Floating Action Button Expand to a new view

Tags: android, user-interface, animation

There are many options available to build a floating action button which pops up a menu upon clicking.But in this case I want to make a floating action button or may be a simple button which transforms into a view to fit into the screen and when another button is clicked the view is reverted back to the button again.

[image: Phase 1(Shrinked)]

[image: Button expanded to view]

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [this example](https://github.com/saulmm/Curved-Fab-Reveal-Example) on Github